# Event AppDomain.AssemblyResolve not fired on COM server

Tags: c#, .net, com

It seems that the event `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` is not fired if the application registering it is started via COM. On the contrary the event handler is regularly called if the application is started by its own, without COM.

On the event documentation it is stated that, in case of more than one handler registered, they are called in order until one returns a not `null` value. I have no control on the COM client so I don't know if this is the reason for the missing call but I have removed the referred assembly after the compilation hence no other handler should be able to return a not null value.

Do you know if this could be the reason for the event handler is not fired or maybe there is something else that I am missing?

An example of COM server follows:

```
public class cPlugin {

    public void Main(object obj1, object obj2) {
        Initialize();
        RealMain();
    }

    private void Initialize() {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(MyResolveEventHandler);
    }

    private void RealMain() {
        ClassLibraryHelloWorld.Class1 cl = new ClassLibraryHelloWorld.Class1();
        cl.SayHello();
    }

    private Assembly MyResolveEventHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args) {
        //This handler is called only when the common language runtime tries to bind to the assembly and fails.

        //Retrieve the list of referenced assemblies in an array of AssemblyName.
        Assembly MyAssembly, objExecutingAssemblies;
        string strTempAssmbPath = "";

        objExecutingAssemblies = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        AssemblyName[] arrReferencedAssmbNames = objExecutingAssemblies.GetReferencedAssemblies();

        //Loop through the array of referenced assembly names.
        foreach (AssemblyName strAssmbName in arrReferencedAssmbNames) {
            //Check for the assembly names that have raised the "AssemblyResolve" event.
            if (strAssmbName.FullName.Substring(0, strAssmbName.FullName.IndexOf(",")) == args.Name.Substring(0, args.Name.IndexOf(","))) {
                //Build the path of the assembly from where it has to be loaded.
                strTempAssmbPath = "C:\\Myassemblies\\" + args.Name.Substring(0, args.Name.IndexOf(",")) + ".dll";
                break;
            }

        }
        //Load the assembly from the specified path. 
        MyAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(strTempAssmbPath);

        //Return the loaded assembly.
        return MyAssembly;
    }
}
```

The class `ClassLibraryHelloWorld` is the class that should be loaded at runtime and that is included in the server as a reference not to be copied locally.

**Edit:**

I have found that the problem is not COM related. Infact I have created a test COM client and found that the event is correctly fired. So the problem is in the real COM client, which is a third party program not in my control.
With the debugger I discovered that an event handler is already defined in the real COM client and I am pretty sure that it is not returning `null` when it tries to search for the assembly. For this reason my handler is not called and an exception is thrown.

The new question is: what is the best alternative in this scenario to dynamically load the assembly whitout `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event? Should I have to create a new `AppDomain`?

Comment: Dear @Hans I was waiting for your answer! Thank you :) I already tried the NoInlining attribute but my handler is not called. I'm still getting a System.TypeLoadException 
  HResult=-2146233054

Comment: I've just implemented a COM client to do some tests and the event handler is correctly called while with the real client it is not... I really can't figure out why!

Comment: I think I found what the problem is: the real COM client defines an handler that instead of returning null returns a default assembly or an exception, I don't know exactly because it is a third party program. So now the problem is: how to bypass this behaviour?